# comparing two XmlBeans Objects for equality

Tags: java, xmlbeans

I've an XML Beans Interface called SynonymsRequest with:

```
public interface SynonymsRequest extends org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject {...}
```

I want to test two instances of SynonymsRequest for equality:

```
SynonymsRequest s1 = SynonymsRequest.Factory.newInstance();
s1.setQueryText("blub");
s1.setRequesterId(BigInteger.valueOf(1));       
SynonymsRequest s2 = SynonymsRequest.Factory.newInstance();
s2.setQueryText("guck");
s2.setRequesterId(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
```

I've tried the following:

1. `assertTrue(s1.equals(s2));` => assertion does not pass
2. `assertEquals(0, s1.compareTo(s2));` => throws ClassCastException
3. `assertEquals(0, s1.compareValue(s2));` => assertion does not pass (returns 2, not compareable)
4. `assertTrue(s1.valueEquals(s2));` => always returns true, no matter if the two instances are equal

So what is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

If it doesn't impact the performance of your program, you could compare them like this:

```
assertTrue(s1.xmlText().equals(s2.xmlText()));
```

Otherwise, I guess you will have to write your own custom comparator.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, the comparison compares two simple values only. It cannot deduct your desired comparison algorithm.

Or I don't understand what exactly do you mean?

Comment: ok, so complex xml types cannot be testet for equality in xmlbeans without writing your own equals method?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I expect so. It's quite difficult to invent an universal comparison algorithm for most cases.

Comment: @Kan, you're a little wrong. Eclipse can generate equals and hashcode methods. The code for determining equality based on a set of member variable is pretty standard.

Comment: @Tim Bender: The fact that some IDEs assist you write equals/hashCode doesn't tell anything about XmlBeans library. It can generate for any class.

Answer (score 0):

XmlBeans doesn't support a deep comparison so you'll have to write your own.  There was a thread on the dev mailing list a while ago about a schema-aware comparison, but I'm not sure anything became of it:

http://www.mail-archive.com/dev@xmlbeans.apache.org/msg01960.html

Answer (score 0):

Noticed this a while back - if the two objects have toString() methods generated when they were made, then you can to an .equals on the toString() methods of the objects. These can be compared with relativ ease, since they will check if the output xml is equivalent.